# How to implement the display and edit for some custom icons such as ":)", ":("?

Tags: iphone

I want to implement the input and display for some custom icons such as ":)", ":(", "@name", etc by UITextField. Maybe I can hook up the action of valueChanged for the text field to a method which scans the text.
But how can I put a imageView in UITextField? Even if the icon is set as a subview of UITextField, how can I edit this icon(shift or remove)?

Comment: You can add the image as a subview but handling deleting etc on that image will be tricky. You need to constantly check the cursor location and hook the keypress events to handle backspace etc. You can add subviews to textfield in the same was as you add padding.

Answer (score 1):

You could replace the `:)` with an [emoji](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emoji) smile: http://pukupi.com/post/1964

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I want to make some custom emotion icon in my app. How can I do that?

Comment: Wel I think you will have te write you own text view.

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
  NSString *emo;
  UIImage *smile;
  if ( [emo compare:@":)" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch] == NSOrderedSame )
    smile = [UIImage imageNamed:@"smile.png"];
```

Comment: Yes, the emtion string would be find and the corresponding icon was read. But, after this icon was loaded, how can I make this icon displayed in TextField?

Comment: It's not easy, you can addSubview to textfield, but you need to create spaces, mantain characters, etc..